# Глагол "быть" употребляется как переходный глагол?

Tags: грамматика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный кусок текста из романа "Воскресения" Толстого.

Вот задает вопрос: "Какого вы были мнения о Масловой?" 
А я думал, что здесь должно быть так: "Каким(или какое?) у вас было мнение о Масловой?", или так: "Какого вы имели мнения о Масловой?"

Интересно, можно так говорить или нет? Я боюсь сомневаться, ведь это же произведение... Автор знаменитый тоже))

Кстати, ответ тоже немного странный для меня: "Самый хороший." Но это, кажется, можно оправдать: Может, она имеет в виду: "Самый хороший(человек)."

Comment: Не стоит давать текст картинкой. Лучше скопировать и привести ссылку.

Comment: Кстати, я посмотрел ваш вопрос на англоязычном аналоге ресурса, но он закрыт, ответить не смог. Если вы не разобрались с падежами (в выражениях "взять мёду" и "с боку на бок"), повторите вопрос здесь.

Answer (score 3):

Источник:

> - А какого вы были мнения  о  Масловой?  -  краснея  и  робея,  спросил > назначенный от суда кандидат на судебную должность, защитник
>   Масловой.
>
> - Самый хороший, - отвечала Китаева, - девушка образованный и  шикарна. Он воспитывался в хороший семейство и по-французски  могли 
>   читать.  Он  пил иногда немного лишнего, но никогда не забывался.
>   Совсем хороший девушка.

http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=18556&public_page=19

> Глагол “быть” употребляется как переходный глагол?

Нет. Но ваш пример не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. 
Переходным называется глагол, допускающий или требующий при себе прямого дополнения. (Строго говоря, в отношении русского языка надо сделать небольшие оговорки, но их я опускаю, они не на рассматриваемые случаи). 
В примере ничего подобного нет. 
Сравните - "бить девушку" (бить = глагол переходный).

> Вот задает вопрос: "Какого вы были мнения о Масловой?"

Здесь абсолютно правильная грамматическая форма. Глагол "быть" управляет **родительным падежом единственного числа** сочетания "какого мнения", что, естественно, не делает его переходным, форма "мнения" - родительный падеж. Возможно, вы смешали его с омонимичным винительным множественного (и на этом основание сочли "быть" переходным), но это ошибочно.
Да, управление родительным падежом для глагола "быть" - функция нехарактерная, но возможная. Используется для выражения качества объекта и обязательно с определением-прилагательным (крайне редко - причастием) или вопросительным местоимением "какого":  "Он (был) большого роста" - "Какого роста он (был)?". 
Последний пример - грамматически эквивалентен рассматриваемому случаю.
Какого роста он был?" = "Какого вы были мнения?"

> "Каким у вас было мнение о Масловой?",

Это возможно, но менее употребительно в современном языке. Оно выражает (нестрого) предположение о том, что мнение изменилось или могло измениться. В некотором это лексическое соответствие исчезнувшему в русском языке давнопрошедшему времени (английскому, например): *"Каким у вас было мнение о Масловой, до того как вы узнали о ней (то-то и то-то)"?* - вот это было бы вполне правильно.

Вообще же в этом случае используется творительный падеж, и он употребляется далеко не только в этом случае, например, "я буду доктором", "я был моряком" - вполне продуктивная форма, но тут другой смысл.

> "Какое у вас было мнение о Масловой?"

Это вполне возможно, смысл тот же, но в современном языке относится скорее к книжной речи. Падеж здесь тоже родительный ("у вас", а дополнение - в именительном) но они тут в особой функции, форма "У меня (у тебя, у них) есть (был, будет)" - связанная, передает обладание чем-то, в других конструкциях не используется. Просто так её не объяснить, носителям английского обычно понятна схема
"У меня есть машина" - There is a car at me" = I has got a car.
"У них двое детей" - There are two children at them" = They have two children. 
Только в таком смысле и надо понимать эту форму. По контексту в фашем примере она не совсем уместна.

> "Какого вы имели мнения о Масловой?"

Э, нет, это невозможно. Глагол "иметь" в отличие от "быть" родительным падежи никогда не управляет. Здесь нужен винительный: *"Какое вы имели мнения о Масловой?"*. Впрочем и эта форма не совсем правильная стилистически, глагол "иметь" в значении обладания используется больше в книжной речи, живая разговорная речь использует конструкцию "у вас есть (было,будет...)", о которой я писал выше.

> Интересно, можно так говорить или нет? Я боюсь сомневаться, ведь это
>   же произведение... Автор знаменитый тоже))

Это речь не автора, а героя. Передает неграмотность героя (в данном случае - деланную, нарочистую).

> Кстати, ответ тоже немного странный для меня: "Самый хороший."

Ну эта та же самая показная неграмотность героя.

> Но это, кажется, можно оправдать: Может, она имеет в виду: "Самый
>   хороший(человек)."

Нет, это вряд ли. Китаева вообще не заботится о правильной речи, оправдывать её не надо, да и вряд ли она могла иметь в виду подобную конструкцию. Её спросили про мнение - она про мнение и отвечает. А так бы получилось, что она отвечает на грамматически по-другому поставленный вопрос (хотя по смыслу - тот же).

Маленький совет. Не пытайтесь осмыслить русский язык через Толстого. Его грамматика (а стиль - тем более!) тяжеловата не только для изучающих, но и для носителей русского языка. Он сам по-французски писал понятнее и лучше, чем по-русски ))).

добавлено

> Насчет китаевы, даже не ожидал такого))

**Китаевой**. Это фамилия, требует заглавной буквы и формы притяжательного прилагательного (какой? чьей?) -  Китаевой.
Она не настолько неграмотна, но немного притворяется.

Comment: Желательно исправить в ответе:  "они не на рассматриваемые случаи" -> "они не для рассматриваемых случаев"; "фуннция" -> "функция"; "фашем" -> "вашем"

Comment: @М_Г спасибо, исправил опечатки, какие увидел, С первым вашим предложением не согласен, это не опечатка. Зачем менять хорошее шило на плохое мыло?

Answer (score 1):

1) Из словаря: МНЕНИЕ,  1. Суждение, выражающее оценку кого-, чего-л., отношение к кому-, чему-л., взгляд на кого-, что-л. Общественное м. Предвзятое м. Борьба мнений. Высказать какое-л. м. Уважать чужое м. Придерживаться своего мнения. Не иметь собственного мнения. **Быть невысокого мнения о ком-л.** (плохо относиться к кому-л., низко оценивать чьи-л. способности, черты характера и т.п.).

Быть хорошего/плохого/невысокого/другого мнения ― это устойчивое выражение.
**Какое у вас мнение, он обо всем имеет свое мнение, какого вы мнения о ней** ― всё это различные формы для одного и того же вопроса "что вы об этом/о нём/ о ней думаете?".

2) **Ответ "самый хороший"** означает, что персонаж плохо знает русский язык и использует неправильные грамматические формы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Насчет китаевы, даже не ожидал такого))